# Modifying query (showing the latest row for each item)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to obtain the latest row for each item (the latest row of each item is identified with the request_id within the row)

These are my tables:

```
create table table_price_product 
(
    LIST_HEADER_ID int, 
    LIST_LINE_ID int,   
    ITEM_CODE int,  
    PRICE VARCHAR(32),  
    START_DATE_ACTIVE varchar(32),  
    END_DATE_ACTIVE varchar(32),    
    INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG varchar(5),  
    REQUEST_ID int, 
    LAST_UPDATE_DATE varchar(32)
);

create table table_price_list 
(
    LIST_HEADER_ID int, 
    NAME varchar(32),   
    CURRENCY_CODE varchar (32),
    REQUEST_ID int
);
```

This is my [SQLFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dEoLRR9aWqu2iLkAGe3ZWd/0)

This is my query BUT i am not getting what i want:

```
SELECT man.LIST_HEADER_ID number,
       man.ITEM_CODE item_code,
       man.PRICE,
       man.START_DATE_ACTIVE,
       man.END_DATE_ACTIVE,
       man.REQUEST_ID
FROM table_price_product man,
     table_price_list pal
WHERE man.LIST_HEADER_ID = pal.LIST_HEADER_ID
  AND (man.START_DATE_ACTIVE IS NULL
OR man.END_DATE_ACTIVE IS NULL)
AND man.REQUEST_ID = pal.REQUEST_ID
ORDER BY man.LAST_UPDATE_DATE ASC;
```

**This is what my query shows:**

```
> CODE  |SKU     |PRICE  |START_DATE_ACTIVE|END_DATE_ACTIVE|REQUEST_ID
> 655234|99342435|9999   |       null      |null           |42937536
> 655234|99342435|8888   |       null      |null           |42937507
> 655234|99342435|7445   |       null      |null           |42937506
> 655234|99342435|5545   |       null      |null           |42937505
> 655234|99342435|2254   |       null      |null           |42937504
> 655234|89992424|18799  |       null      |null           |72254787
> 655234|89992424|18444  |       null      |null           |72254780
> 655234|89992424|18005  |       null      |null           |72254781
> 655234|89992424|18045  |       null      |null           |72254782
> 655234|91123323|1049   |       null      |null           |88755875
> 655234|91123323|1000   |       null      |null           |88755865
> 655234|91123323|9878   |       null      |null           |88755862
> 655234|91123323|10498  |       null      |null           |88755861
> 655234|91123323|1044   |       null      |null           |88755860
```

But i want to obtain this output (the highest request_id for each item):

> ```
> CODE  |SKU     |PRICE  |START_DATE_ACTIVE|END_DATE_ACTIVE|REQUEST_ID
> 655234|99342435|9999   |       null      |null           |42937536
> 465408|89992424|18799  |       null      |null           |72254787
> 464062|91123323|1049   |       null      |null           |88755875
> ```

I've tried to solve this by using *over* within partition but it did not work for me

### Can help me?

EDIT: i'm using Oracle database

Comment: which sql engine are you using?

Comment: Hey dude!, sorry. I'm using Oracle database

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also - please use the **most appropriate** datatypes for your columns - do **NOT** store date or numerical values like `price` as `Varchar`!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following using window function `row_number`, Also you should always use explicit joins.

```
SELECT 
  man.LIST_HEADER_ID number,
  man.ITEM_CODE item_code,
  man.PRICE,
  man.START_DATE_ACTIVE,
  man.END_DATE_ACTIVE,
  man.REQUEST_ID
from
(
  SELECT 
    man.LIST_HEADER_ID number,
    man.ITEM_CODE item_code,
    man.PRICE,
    man.START_DATE_ACTIVE,
    man.END_DATE_ACTIVE,
    man.REQUEST_ID,
    row_number() over (partition by SKU order by request_id desc) as rnk
  FROM table_price_product man
  join table_price_list pal
  ON man.LIST_HEADER_ID = pal.LIST_HEADER_ID
  AND man.REQUEST_ID = pal.REQUEST_ID
  where (man.START_DATE_ACTIVE IS NULL
  OR man.END_DATE_ACTIVE IS NULL)
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, dude!.I'm checking it out. I'm a little confused about "val". What it is actually doing?

Comment: @Student_new `val` is just an alias to subquery.

Comment: Hey dude, i'm getting the same error over and over again: " FROM keyword not found where expected". What's going on?

Comment: Hey dude, yeah.. the problem is now i'm geting this error: "Ambiguous column name error "

Comment: @Student_new you have to solve it yourself, look around and you should get it why it is happening.

Comment: Done!, my bad :)